# Nodejs mongoClient.connect fails due to username/password setup in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, node-mongodb-native

> When i try to connect like this it **fails** when i use database as
>   **eventsstore**

[mongoClient.connect](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html)

`MongoClient.connect('mongodb://tom:pass@localhost:27017/eventsstore',function(err,db){
    if(err){
        console.log('NOT CONNECTED')
    }
    console.log('CONNECTED')
    var collection = db.collection('events').insert({mydata:123}, function(err, res){})
})`

**Note** : Also database **eventsstore** is created by admin login

> It Passes/connects **successfully** when i use database as **admin**

`MongoClient.connect('mongodb://tom:pass@localhost:27017/admin',function(err,db){
    if(err){
        console.log('NOT CONNECTED')
    }
    console.log('CONNECTED')
    var collection = db.collection('events').insert({mydata:123}, function(err, res){})
})`

> this is how my **mongo** user **tom** [***SUPERUSER***](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/built-in-roles/#superuser-roles) permission look in mongo

`db.getUser('tom')`

`[
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdmin",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "clusterAdmin",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide authentication db

var opts  = {db: {authSource: 'admin'}}

mongo.connect('mongodb://tom:pass@localhost:27017/admin', opts, function(err, db) {

}